# Como manipular vários bancos com Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate

Estou testando o funcionamento do Hibernate e me deparei com uma dúvida. Tenho a seguinte configuração:

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbFatura?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Fatura.hbm.xml"/> -->
        <mapping class="org.hibernate.tutorial.domain.Fatura"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**SessionFactory**

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try{
            return new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation factory failed. " + ex);
            throw  new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Nessa configuração, estou determinando o banco que vou utilizar no caso o `dbFatura`:

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbFatura?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
```

O mapeamento e a manipulação de dados, funciona corretamente. Mas, aí entra as dúvidas:

- É possível manipular vários bancos na mesmo aplicação? (ex: dbFatura,
  dbMovimentacoes)
- Se é possível, como fazer a mudança de banco na execução da classe?
- Posso criar vários arquivos `.xml`, para movimentar cada banco separadamente a partir da `SessionFactory`?

Comment: Aqui tem o que você precisa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921865/how-to-connect-to-multiple-databases-in-hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma alternativa encontrada, para conseguir utilizar dois bancos, é criando dois arquivos de configuração do `hibernate` e manipular conforme a utilização:

**hibernate-event.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/event?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="org.hibernate.Event"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**hibernate-client.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/client?useTimezone=true&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="org.hibernate.Client"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Na classe de utilidades, que manipula a criação da `Session`, quando o método for chamado, ele recebe o nome do arquivo que deseja manipular e inicia a conexão de acordo com o arquivo que escolher (o arquivo do banco 1 ou o arquivo do banco 2):

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(String configFile) {
        try{
            configFile += ".cfg.xml";
            return new Configuration().configure(configFile).buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation factory failed. " + ex);
            throw  new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

E por fim, na classe que manipula os dados do banco, para cada método específico, é necessário passar o arquivo do banco que deseja trabalhar.

**ManagerDatabase.java**

Selecionar todos os clientes:

```
public List<Cliente> selectAllClients() {
    List<Cliente> result;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory("hibernate-client").openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        query = session.createQuery("FROM clients");

        result = query.list();

        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        System.out.println("Was found an error in execution!" + he.getCause());
        result = null;
        return result;
    } finally {
        closeSession();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Selecionar todos os eventos:

```
public List<Cliente> selectAllEvents() {
    List<Cliente> result;
    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory("hibernate-event").openSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        query = session.createQuery("FROM events");

        result = query.list();

        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        System.out.println("Was found an error in execution!" + he.getCause());
        result = null;
        return result;
    } finally {
        closeSession();
    }
    return result;
}
```